# Numpy random choice of tuples

Tags: python, numpy, random

I'm having trouble to create an array of random choices, where a choice is a tuple.

I get the error: `a must be 1-dimensional`

Here is an example:

```
choices = ((0,0,0),(255,255,255))
numpy.random.choice(choices,4)
```

Is there any other way to do this?

Expected result:

a numpy array consiting of 4 elements randomly picked from the choices tuple.

```
((0,0,0),(0,0,0),(255,255,255),(255,255,255))
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please provide more code.

Comment: @sshashank124 added expected result

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use `choice` to choose the 1dim *indices* into the array, then index it.

In the example you provided, only the **number** of possible choices affects the nature of the choice, not the actual values (0, 255). Choosing indices is the 1dim problem `choice` knows how to handle.

```
choices = numpy.array([[0,0,0],[255,255,255]])
idx = numpy.random.choice(len(choices),4)
choices[idx]
```

Comment: I was thinking about this solution, shame that it involves creating a temp array for indexes

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski actually two temp arrays: arange and idx

Comment: the arange is unnecessary since the tuple indecies start from 0, choice(len(choices),4) will suffice

Answer (score 6):

Just adding this answer to provide a `non-numpy` based answer:

```
choices = ((0,0,0),(255,255,255))

from random import choice

print tuple(choice(choices) for _ in range(4))
```

Comment: This doesn't give you the option of choice without replacement tho.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to specifically sample without replacement, you can try:

```
import random
choices = ((0,0,0),(1,1,1),(2,2,2),(3,3,3))
random.sample(choices, 2)
```

Comment: This should be the top answer, altough it uses random.sample