# 2D version of numpy random choice with weighting

Tags: python, numpy, random

This relates to this earlier post: [Numpy random choice of tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23445936/numpy-random-choice-of-tuples)

I have a 2D numpy array and want to choose from it using a 2D probability array. The only way I could think to do this was to flatten and then use the modulo and remainder to convert the result back to a 2D index

```
import numpy as np
# dummy data
x=np.arange(100).reshape(10,10)

# dummy probability array
p=np.zeros([10,10])
p[4:7,1:4]=1.0/9

xy=np.random.choice(x.flatten(),1,p=p.flatten())
index=[int(xy/10),(xy%10)[0]] # convert back to index
print(index)
```

which gives

> > [5, 2]

but is there a cleaner way that avoids flattening and the modulo?  i.e. I could pass a list of coordinate tuples as x, but how can I then handle the weights?

Comment: I think this method is fine, you could replace division/modulo by [unravel_index](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to directly specify a 2D shaped array of probabilities. So raveling should be fine. However to get the corresponding 2D shaped indices from the flat index you can use [`np.unravel_index`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html)

```
index= np.unravel_index(xy.item(), x.shape)
# (4, 2)
```

---

For multiple indices, you can just stack the result:

```
xy=np.random.choice(x.flatten(),3,p=p.flatten())

indices = np.unravel_index(xy, x.shape)
# (array([4, 4, 5], dtype=int64), array([1, 2, 3], dtype=int64))
np.c_[indices]
array([[4, 1],
       [4, 2],
       [5, 3]], dtype=int64)
```

where `np.c_` [stacks along the right hand axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10894323/what-does-the-c-underscore-expression-c-do-exactly) and gives the same result as

```
np.column_stack(indices)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `numpy.random.randint` to generate an index, for example:

```
# assumes p is a square array
ij = np.random.randint(p.shape[0], size=p.ndim) # size p.ndim = 2 generates 2 coords

# need to convert to tuple to index correctly
p[tuple(i for i in ij))]
>>> 0.0
```

You can also index multiple random values at once:

```
ij = np.random.randint(p.shape[0], size=(p.ndim, 5)) # get 5 values
p[tuple(i for i in ij))]
>>> array([0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.11111111, 0.        ])
```

Comment: nice thanks, the only issue with randint is that I don't think it allows me to apply a weighting, or am I wrong?

Comment: No you're right I think. `randint` doesn't have a probability argument, but `choice` does. Good to know!

Comment: thanks for the input anyway, useful for non-weighted examples.